# incorrect mean from PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

So here's an interesting thing:

Using python 2.7:

I've got a dataframe of about 5,100 entries, each with a number (melting point) in a column titled 'Tm'. Using the code:

```
self.sort_df[['Tm']].mean(axis=0)
```

I get a mean of:

```
Tm    92.969204
dtype: float64
```

This doesn't make sense because no entry has a Tm of greater than 83.

Does .mean() not work for this many values? I've tried pairing down the dataset and it seems to work for ~1,000 entries but considering I have full dataset of 150,000 to run at once, I'd like to know if I need to find a different way to calculate the mean.

Comment: Without dataset it's difficult to answer. However, since you said *no entry has a Tm of greater than 83*, you may want to check `df['Tm'].max()` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more readable syntax would be :

```
sort_df['Tm'].mean()
```

Try to do a `sort_df['Tm'].value_counts()` or `sort_df['Tm'].max()` to see what values are present. Some unexpected values must have crept up.

The `.mean` function gives accurate result irrespective of the size.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I may have been importing the Tm values inside a Decimal() function, though it doesn't stop a normal loop from getting a more reasonable mean. I'll use your suggestions to see if something's fishy though.

Comment: I was importing the `Tm` vaules wrapped in the `Decimal()` function, which was throwing it off. I switched to importing them as `float` type and the mean is correct now.